# String value to XMLGregorianCalendar and change the format to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, string, date, calendar, xmlgregoriancalendar

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException, DatatypeConfigurationException {
    
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
            Date date = format.parse("2022-04-13T09:54:54-04:00");
    
            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            cal.setTime(date);
    
            XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregCal =  DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);
    
            System.out.println(xmlGregCal);
    
    //        Expected is 2022-04-13 in XMLGregorianCalendar value
    //        But getting 2021-12-26T00:00:00.000+11:00
        }
    }
```

**Expected is 2022-04-13 in XMLGregorianCalendar value. But getting 2021-12-26T00:00:00.000+11:00.
Can some expert please help here?**

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`,  `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `GregorianCalendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first two in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Letting `XMLGregorianCalendar` do all the work is an alternative option.

Comment: You should decide in which time zone you want the date. If you assume that the input string is already in the desired time zone, you should check this assumption.

Comment: If you must use SimpleDateFormat, check the javadocs for the proper date format notation!  You might want yyyy not YYYY.  Confirm that the initial "parse" is doing what you expect before you add the complication of the second calendar.

Comment: *must use SimpleDateFormat* @BipedPhill No one must do that, or at least only programmers with evil bosses who force them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems.

- You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.
- Your formatting pattern fails to match your data being parsed.

Parse your input as a `OffsetDateTime` object. Your input text complies with the ISO 8601 standard format used by default in *java.time*. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2022-04-13T09:54:54-04:00" ) ;
```

You have no need to further involve more legacy classes such as `GregorianCalendar` or `XMLGregorianCalendar`. Job done. There is no point to using or studying these classes. Their functionality has been entirely replaced by *java.time*.

You can generate text in standard ISO 8601 format by calling `OffsetDate#toString`.

```
String output = odt.toString() ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/H8BauQ).

> 2022-04-13T09:54:54-04:00

You said:

> change the format to XMLGregorianCalendar

Date-time objects do not have a “format”. Text has a format. `GregorianCalendar`, `XMLGregorianCalendar`, and `OffsetDateTime` are not text.